# Broadcom wireless adapter shows up but can't be connected

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, wget

My computer keeps saying no adapter found. I can't include what the terminal said because I have to copy and paste it here. I can't do that because I have no internet on my Ubuntu operating system in order to paste my results here. I don't even think I can post a picture. What information do you even need? I have internet on windows so how come I can't get it on Ubuntu? The wifi icon that is supposed to be at the top right isn't even there. The internet will only work if I plug an ethernet cable from my router into my computer. My broadcom wireless adapter shows up but can't be connected for some reason.

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info --2018-03-14 19:31:33-- https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Name or service not known. wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
```

Comment: "The internet will only work if I plug an ethernet cable from my router into my computer." I suggest you do just that long enough to post the wireless info results. We can't help you much without details. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps you can download your WiFi drivers on another machine then move them via USB and setup them up on the machine giving you troubles?

Comment: It's the same machine. I'm dual booting Ubuntu beside Linux.

Comment: I already gave a script. What command do you want me to type to get wireless info results.

Comment: wget the script, run it and let it produce the full diagnostic report and post it here.

Comment: How do I wget the script?